# SQL If two column values dont match, then show all values that dont match

Tags: sql

I have two tables joined up together
I need to see if Product Code from table 1 (On the left) matches with the on on the right, based on their barcodes.. I have managed to inner join the barcodes and show only barcodes that match up. Just the prdouct code is the problem now...

[image: Example]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data (and expected result) as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: Add your sample data as text , not as an image and show us the query you have so far

Comment: And let us know which DBMS product you are using

Comment: What SQL technology are you using? Where is your query?  Also what is the problem you are referring to?  If you want ones that dont match just use != in your join.

Comment: Hi Brad, how would I re script it using the !=?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.code = t1.product_code and t2.barcode = t1.barcode
                 );
```

This selects rows from `table1` with no matches in `table2`.

Comment: Thats perfect! Thanks for your positive reply haha

Comment: what does the * do?

Comment: select every column from table 1